# timestamp to date conversion problem in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a timestamp like `1397105576` and I need to convert it to data format. I used:

```
echo $today = date('20y-m-d H:m:s',"1397105576");
```

I am getting:

> Severity: Warning
>   Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given

in the codeigniter framework.

update:
 i found the answer

the vaiable should be converted to long
ie

```
echo $today = date('20y-m-d H:m:s',intval("1397105576"));
```

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question, post them as a separate answer, In this case, `intval` is converting the string to an `int`, not a `long`; you could just use `1397105576` instead of the circuitous `intval("1397105576")`, but it shouldn't matter either way -- PHP will deal with the argument being a string. If this really did somehow solve your problem, you can post a separate answer or accept [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598489/timestamp-to-date-conversion-problem-in-php/3598509#3598509) which appears to be the same solution

Comment: It's NOT "H:m:s", it's "H:i:s". Seems that several answers don't notice this mistake.

Answer (score 3):

`echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s',"1397105576");`

**Returns**

`2014-04-10 14:04:56`

**Update:**

That should work in codeigniter also...however there is a CI function that does something similar as above:

```
$datestring = "Year: %Y Month: %m Day: %d - %h:%i %a";
$time = time();

echo mdate($datestring, $time);
```

More about this can be found at the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html). You might be interested in the `unix_to_human()` function in particular.

Answer (score 2):

It seems everywhere except for Russell Dias made the mistake of using m as minutes and not i

Y-m-d H:i:s NOT "Y-m-d H:m:s"

Answer (score 1):

your code is working correctly although try it again like this:

```
<?php
echo $today = date('Y-m-d H:m:s',1397105576);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
I'm going to leave my answer here as a matter of pointing out/teaching you the non-CodeIgnitor sanitized version of PHP's object/typing (+date function!) system, but I HIGHLY suggest using, and accepting, Russell Dias' answer.

---

Is your example 100% literal?

Is your line of code literally `echo $today = date('20y-m-d H:m:s',"1397105576");` or is it something more like `echo $today = date('20y-m-d H:m:s',"$date");`?

If it's the latter, and the variable is being created by a class, then it may not be properly-typed.

You could probably use… I think an int would suffice here, I think you could do something like `echo $today = date('20y-m-d H:m:s',(int)$date);`, again, assuming that your line of code is not in-fact literal.

I'm not 100% sure that int would work, if it doesn't, (float) is the only other numeric type that possible could. Perhaps (string)?

See [Type Juggling](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

---

As an aside, why are you using 20y? Please change that to a Y

From [PHP's Date Docs](http://docs.php.net/date):
`Y | A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits | Examples: 1999 or 2003`
`y | A two digit representation of a year              | Examples: 99 or 03`